# A result on a fibration that is an epimorphism of simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Consider $p:E\rightarrow B$ to be a fibration of simplicial sets. I want to see that if $p$ is an epimorphism and $E$ is fibrant then $B$ is also fibrant.

I have come to the conclusion that to solve this problem I just need to find a lift

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
. @>{}>> E\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Lambda^k_n @>{}>>B
\end{CD}

from $\Lambda^k_n$ to $E$. Now by assumption we know that $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a fibration. Now I belive that $\cdot \rightarrow \Lambda^k_n$ is a trivial cofibration , since it's an homotopy equivalence on the geometric realizations and a monomorphism. Now due to well know facts on the model structure we have that such a lift exists.
I wanted to make sure that all the facts that I am using , namely that $\cdot \rightarrow \Lambda^k_n$ is a trivial cofibration are correct. Also that if we have an epimorphism $p:E\rightarrow B$ then the maps $p_n:E_n\rightarrow B_n$ are surjective.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is true that any morphism $\Delta^0 \to \Lambda^n_k$ is an anodyne extension and therefore has the llp wrt Kan fibrations. It is also true that $p : E \to B$ is an epimorphism if and only if each $p_n : E_n \to B_n$ is surjective, but for the purposes of this proof you only need to know that $p_0 : E_0 \to B_0$ is surjective.